# One-to-one complex cosine

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following mapping one-to-one?

$f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:z \mapsto \cos(z)$

where

$A = \{z : z \in \mathbb{C}, 0 < \operatorname{Re}{(z)} < \pi\} \cup \{z: z \in \mathbb{C},  \operatorname{Re}{(z)} = 0, \operatorname{Im}{(z)} \geq 0 \} \cup  \{z: z \in \mathbb{C},  \operatorname{Re}{(z)} = \pi, \operatorname{Im}{(z)} \leq 0 \}$

Comment: You should probably show your attempts so far.

Answer (score 2):

I mapled some pictures ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

[image: y varies]  [image: x varies]